# Not able to stop nginx server

Tags: nginx

I am unable to stop nginx server by the command
 sudo /etc/init.d/nginx stop

tried killing it through pid

First I check the process which is listening to a port via this
command.

lsof -Pnl +M -i4

Then I kill it by

sudo kill -9 pid

The app is still running!!.
After that when i again do

lsof -Pnl +M -i4

I see that a new process is now listening on the same port, for which
i tried to kill the process.

Regards,
Pankaj

Answer (score 1):

Did you try stopping the process as root?

Answer (score 0):

check that path to pid in initscript and path to pid in nginx.conf are identical

Comment: in nginx.conf the line for path to pid is commented.  In initscript what I understand by this is the file /etc/init.d/nginx has the following contents http://pastie.org/1508070

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the process is not a zombie?
When it is a zombie, in most cases only a reboot will help.

You can read more about zombies [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/killing-zombie-process.html).